# ¿Como insertar imágenes creadas con Faker desde una prueba de Phpunit en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Estoy tratando de probar que las reglas sobre las imágenes en el validator dentro de mi controlador funcionen bien, ya valide todas las reglas anteriores y todo correcto.

este es mi validator:

```
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'tradename' => 'required|between:2,50',
                'social_reason' => 'required|between:2,100',
                'rfc' => 'required|between:12,13',
                'tire_fee' => 'numeric|required|min:0.01|max:99.99',
                'fee_currency_type' => 'numeric|required|between:1,3',
                'logo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
            ]);
```

la parte que no me funciona bien es la de logo, porque aunque ya verifique que me mande mensajes de error cuando el logo no sea imagen o cuando sea un archivo pero no con esas extensiones y esas dos pruebas ya pasaron correctamente.

Las dos pruebas de PhpUnit:

```
public function testCreateCompanyWithoutImageData()
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials();
    $credentials['logo']=0;
    $response = $this->post('/api/company/register', $credentials);
    $response->assertStatus(401);
    $response->assertJson([
        "status"=> false,
        "errors"=> [
            "logo"=>  [Lang::get('validation.image', ["attribute" => "logo"])]
        ]
    ]);
}

public function testCreateCompanyWithBadImageData()
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials();
    $credentials['logo']='/tmp/13b73edae8443990be1aa8f1a483bc27.gif';
    $response = $this->post('/api/company/register', $credentials);
    $response->assertStatus(401);
    $response->assertJson([
        "status"=> false,
        "errors"=> [
            "logo"=>[
                Lang::get('validation.image', ["attribute" => "logo"]),
                Lang::get('validation.mimes', ["attribute" => "logo", "values" => "jpeg, jpg, png"])]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

El problema radica cuando en teoría quiero probar insertar todos los datos correctamente y me vuelve a dar el error de que no es una imagen.

```
   [data:protected] => {"status":false,"errors":{"logo":["El campo logo debe ser una imagen."]}}
```

Aun y cuando la prueba que cree para eso esta correcta

```
public function testCreateCompanyWithData()
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials(); //aqui cargo los datos con faker
    $response = $this->post('/api/company/register', $credentials);
    $response->assertStatus(201);
    $response->assertJson([
        "status"=> true,
        "data"=> 'Registro completo'
    ]);
}
```

Y aunque esta bien y los datos que crea estan bien me sigue dando el error de que no es imagen.

Esta es la función donde creo los datos con faker:

```
public function credentials()
{
    $width = 640;
    $height = 480;
    $dir = '/tmp';

    $credentials = [
        'tradename' => $this->faker->company,
        'social_reason' =>  $this->faker->catchPhrase,
        'rfc' =>  'raur111111as7',
        'tire_fee' => number_format(15.99,2),
        'fee_currency_type' => rand(1, 3),
        'logo' => $this->faker->image($dir, $width, $height, 'cats', true, true, 'Faker')
    ];
    return $credentials;
}
```

Creo que el principal problema es que no se si estoy creando bien la imagen falsa, solo que ya intente cambiar algunas cosas y de todos modos no logro hacer que pase esa prueba me da el mensaje de error que mostré arriba

Así se ven los datos cuando los mando llamar:

```
[31-Jul-2020 20:04:16 UTC] Array
(
    [tradename] => Monahan-Corwin
    [social_reason] => Decentralized multimedia knowledgebase
    [rfc] => raur111111as7
    [tire_fee] => 15.99
    [fee_currency_type] => 3
    [logo] => /tmp/914e020fb594bc8c1c888c5c9253fae8.jpg
)
```

Para aclarar estoy trabajando mis rutas como api y no como web